# Run a Continuous Windows Background Task without Eating Memory

Tags: c#, windows, skype4com, itunes-sdk

I wrote a short C# script to execute when my computer starts up. Its function is to monitor iTunes and display a fun message as my Skype status stating what artist I'm listening to.

It creates an iTunesApp object and adds a listener which detects when the track changes. The problem is that I need to use a `while(true)` loop to keep my app open in the background, or else it will just run and close. I thought this was okay until I looked in Task Manager and realized this small program is using 15%-20% of the CPU!

Is there a better approach?

Here is the heart of the code, to get an idea:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    iTunesApp = new iTunesAppClass();
    iTunesApp.OnPlayerPlayEvent += ITunesApp_OnPlayerPlayEvent;
    while (true)
    { }
}

private static void ITunesApp_OnPlayerPlayEvent(object iTrack)
{
    var currentArtist = iTunesApp.CurrentTrack.Artist;
    if (currentArtist != LastArtist)
    {
        LastArtist = currentArtist;
        var message = GetMessage(currentArtist);
        UpdateSkypeStatus(message);
        UpdateLog(message);
    }
}
```

The full project is at https://github.com/ericsundquist/SkypeTunes.

Comment: Application.Run();

Comment: You have a while(true) loop and no release of CPU. Not the RIGHT solution, but you could add a Thread.sleep() call inside that loop and it would at least release CPU until you can do it the right way.

Comment: [Application.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx).

Comment: It doesn't matter that your program is small, it matters that it continually tasks the CPU. The even smaller program `while (true) {}` would have the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait with [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx), and set() it when your program needs to close. In my example below call Stop to end your program.

```
static ManualResetEvent signal;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    iTunesApp = new iTunesAppClass();
    iTunesApp.OnPlayerPlayEvent += ITunesApp_OnPlayerPlayEvent;

    signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    signal .WaitOne();
}

public static void Stop()
{
    signal.Set();
}

private static void ITunesApp_OnPlayerPlayEvent(object iTrack)
{

    var currentArtist = iTunesApp.CurrentTrack.Artist;
    if (currentArtist != LastArtist)
    {
        LastArtist = currentArtist;
        var message = GetMessage(currentArtist);
        UpdateSkypeStatus(message);
        UpdateLog(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is superior to the comments suggestion Application.Run() (though that will also work). There are no windows events to be processed, so it is extraneous to pump the message loop just to keep the console app open. `Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit."); Console.ReadKey(); `would also work.

Comment: @EricJ.: *"it is extraneous to pump the message loop"* - Except, that's not what `Application.Run` does. It calls `GetMessage` deep down, a blocking call that never returns, until there is a message. It doesn't waste resources in the way you imply.

Comment: @IInspectable: Console (and Windows Service) apps don't generally need to call GetMessage in order to function properly. It's not wasting resources  (I didn't mean to imply that) but it is extraneous (which is what I said).

Comment: @EricJ.: Don't console applications use COM objects? Or install keyboard hooks? There are many reasons for a console application to require a message loop.

Comment: @IInspectable: `don't generally need to call GetMessage`. Sure, there are some specific instances where they need to. In my experience, those are outliers, not the general case. It's not the case here.

Comment: @EricJ.: *"It's not the case here."* - How do you know? In my experience, a thread that doesn't need to dispatch messages is rare. If you are absolutely sure that your thread doesn't, by all means, don't implement a message loop. But that is pretty difficult to establish, and failure to implement one when you should have, usually causes very subtle bugs. Calling `Application.Run` is the canonical solution. If you are absolutely, positively sure, that you don't need to dispatch messages, then the solution posted in this answer would also work. I wouldn't recommend it, though.